# Resize / scale left part of a image while right part of remain unchanged using css

Tags: css

I'm working on a CSS layout where I have an image that only need to expand/ resize of border of image (like 5px pixel of left side). so its like two parts, separate this image into two parts and left side only resize. the left part should be 5 pixels wide and expand to the left side, while the right part  should remain fixed to the right side of the container.

here how i need:

[before expand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Kpsb.png)

after expand:

[after expand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pysQ.png)

I've tried using position and width properties to achieve this effect, but I'm faced difficulties expand and positioning the image parts accordingly.

Could someone provide guidance or a CSS solution to achieve this?

Thank you for your help!

edit add code parts:

```
.image-container {
  width: 400px; 
  height: 200px; 
  position: relative;
}

.image-container img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
}


.image-container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 5px; 
  background: url('image_url.png') 0 0 no-repeat; 
  z-index: 1; 
}


.image-container::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: calc(100% -5px)
  height: 100%;
  background: url('image_url.png') 100% 0 no-repeat; 
}




<body>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="image_url.png" alt="Your Image">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: _"the left part should be 5 pixels wide and expand to the left side"_ - the left side of - what? Some ancestor element? The viewport? Will the image be "solid", or can it have alpha-transparent parts?

Comment: hi , its like 5pixels from image, left side to right side, so its a 5pixel width strip of image (left part). that strip need to expand to the parent div's left side border, while other part(right part of image after 5px from left) should remain unchanged (without resize) . thank you